# How to create a Receiver for creating a new Event

Tags: android, calendar, android-manifest

I have created an application that successively adds appointments to a calendar. However i wish now to be able to click the "New Event" button in a calendar program eg. aCalendar and have my program popup. and i think i am a little lost.

in my AndroidManifest.xml

```
    <receiver 
        android:name="com.johnny.CalendarAdd"
        android:enabled="true"
        >
        <intent-filter>
            <data android:pathPrefix="vnd.android.cursor.item/event" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.EDIT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

tryed to change it to.

```
    <activity android:name="CalendarAdd">
      <intent-filter>
        <data android:pathPrefix="vnd.android.cursor.item/event" />
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.EDIT" /> 
      </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

In class file

```
package com.johnny;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.util.Log;

public class CalendarTest extends BroadcastReceiver {
 @Override
 public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
     Log.i("CalendarAdd", "CalendarAdd.onReceive called!");

 }
}
```

when i click the "New Event" button i don't get my app in the list.
I have had a look-around and think i have missed something simple or i am Totally on the wrong path.

Thanks for any Help in advance.

Comment: as suggestion below said so i changed the code example above to show what i have tryed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
            <activity android:name="com.johny.CalendarTest"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.EDIT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.ALTERNATIVE" />

            <data android:host="com.android.calendar" />
            <data android:host="calendar" />
            <data android:scheme="content" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.EDIT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.ALTERNATIVE" />

            <data android:mimeType="vnd.android.cursor.item/event" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

This was the exact code i used and got to work. 
Most of The Answers helped in getting the response. 
The reward went to the person who put most effort into it and achieved what was a result.

Answer (score 3):

**You can't achieve it using Broadcast Receiver**, Broadcast intent-filter will work only when some app broadcast that particular intent, e.g connectivity state got changed, screen got turned off, battery low etc are correct example of system broadcasts. While create calendar event can't be a broadcast & thats why you can't receive it.

**From android documentation regarding Broadcast Receivers:**

> A broadcast receiver is a component that responds to system-wide
>   broadcast announcements. Many broadcasts originate from the system—for
>   example, a broadcast announcing that the screen has turned off, the
>   battery is low, or a picture was captured. Applications can also
>   initiate broadcasts—for example, to let other applications know that
>   some data has been downloaded to the device and is available for them
>   to use. Although broadcast receivers don't display a user interface,
>   they may create a status bar notification to alert the user when a
>   broadcast event occurs. More commonly, though, a broadcast receiver is
>   just a "gateway" to other components and is intended to do a very
>   minimal amount of work. For instance, it might initiate a service to
>   perform some work based on the event.

For achieving desired functionality, you need to register intent-filter for your activity.
Also your manifest should contain read/write calendar permission and event edit/insert intent-filter, e.g.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          package="com.example.CalanderTest"
          android:versionCode="1"
          android:versionName="1.0">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8"/>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CALENDAR" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CALENDAR" />

    <application android:label="@string/app_name" android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher">
        <activity android:name="MyActivity"
                  android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.EDIT" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.INSERT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <data android:mimeType="vnd.android.cursor.item/event" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

for testing it out do below in onclick of some test button:-

```
@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    super.onClick(view);    
    if (view.getId()==R.id.create_event)
    {
       Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_INSERT);
        i.setType("vnd.android.cursor.item/event");
        startActivity(i);
    }
}
```

On clicking of my test button i got menu like in below image, so above code works fine to show your app in App chooser dialog for adding/editing calendar events.
[image]

Now in your activity you can handle this intent using getIntent() and perform action accordingly.
**[You can have a look here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/calendar-provider.html)** for extras supported by Calendar event.
Like **Events.TITLE,Events.EVENT_LOCATION** etc. If you are going to create your own calendar event creator, then you need to handle all such extras Gracefully, for awesome user experience.

Comment: well done you have worked hard for the reward you deserve it.

Answer (score 1):

Place the `<intent-filter>` you defined inside your `<activity>` instead. The user should be given a list of apps (including yours) that can handle that action, so they can select yours if they want to.

`<receiver>`s are for receiving BroadcastIntents, which are a bit different.

Answer (score 0):

Use `<receiver>` as you originally did, and `android:name` should be `com.johnny.CalendarTest` if you wish to register your receiver, since your receiver class name is `CalendarTest`.

[See here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.styleable.html#AndroidManifestReceiver)

`android:name`
`Required name of the class implementing the receiver, deriving from BroadcastReceiver.`

Comment: YES you are correct as this is Defiantly an error in my code. However this does not get me the new appointment intent. thanks for your help so far. any ohter ideas.

Comment: How about `android.intent.action.INSERT`

Comment: No such luck. Thanks anyway

Comment: Perhaps you need to rethink your strategy. Broadcast receivers are only for receiving broadcasts. App like aCalendar is more likely to direct the intent directly to calendar rather than broadcasting it.

Answer (score 0):

> However i wish now to be able to click the "New Event" button in a
>   calendar program eg. aCalendar and have my program popup.

Have you tried the various `action` and `category` filter declarations in your `<intent-filter>`.

For instance:

```
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.EDIT" />
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.PICK" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.OPENABLE" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <data android:mimeType="application/myapp" />
    </intent-filter>
```

See if any of those help you.

See also: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html

Answer (score 0):

From [CalendarController](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Calendar/+/android-4.2.2_r1.1/src/com/android/calendar/CalendarController.java), I can almost be sure that these intent are explicit intent with specific component set. For example, in `launchEditEvent` method.

```
private void launchEditEvent(long eventId, long startMillis, long endMillis, boolean edit) {
    Uri uri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(Events.CONTENT_URI, eventId);
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_EDIT, uri);
    intent.putExtra(EXTRA_EVENT_BEGIN_TIME, startMillis);
    intent.putExtra(EXTRA_EVENT_END_TIME, endMillis);
    intent.setClass(mContext, EditEventActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra(EVENT_EDIT_ON_LAUNCH, edit);
    mEventId = eventId;
    mContext.startActivity(intent);
}
```

The intent is set to be handled by EditEventActivity. So it is impossible to receive such intents in your application. I think the Calendar App make it as an explicit intent because it regard this as an in-app event. If this is not an explicit intent, your code should work, because the component in Calendar App is almost same with what you did.

```
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.EDIT" />
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.INSERT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <data android:mimeType="vnd.android.cursor.item/event" />
    </intent-filter>
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.EDIT" />
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.INSERT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <data android:mimeType="vnd.android.cursor.dir/event" />
    </intent-filter>
```

Answer (score 0):

The aCalendar New Event Intent is as this.

{act=android.intent.action.EDIT typ=vnd.android.cursor.item/event flg=0x20000000 cmp=org.withouthat.acalendar/.edit.EditActivity (has extras)}

And Google Calendar App New Event Intent is as this.

{act=android.intent.action.VIEW cmp=com.android.calendar/.event.EditEventActivity

They are explicit intent.
Your can not receive this intent in your app.
More about intent click [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters.html)

Answer (score 0):

The old answers show me the direction, but I had to do a small modification to make it work:

```
<activity
        android:name=".YourActivity"
        android:exported="true">
    <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.INSERT" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.EDIT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <data android:mimeType="vnd.android.cursor.dir/event" />
     </intent-filter>
</activity>
```